# How to change the delays between key presses in Emacs cua-mode

Tags: emacs

I'm editing a Python file buffer in python-mode, and I want to quickly evaluate a region, so I select the region and press `C-c C-r`. Since I enabled cua-mode, that turns out to be a command that 1) copies the region, 2) backward searches.

I then found actually if I press fast enough, `C-c C-r` sends region for eval, if not, `C-c C-r` runs copy and backward search.

Is there a way to change the delay? It is to fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed; customize the variable `cua-prefix-override-inhibit-delay`, whose default as of Emacs 24.3 is 0.2 seconds. (You can customize just that variable via `M-x customize-variable RET cua-prefix-override-inhibit-delay RET`, or cua-mode settings in general via `M-x customize-group RET cua RET`.)